# Let$ H \triangleleft G$ with $[G:H]=p$, p prime. Show if K < G with $K \nsubseteq H$, then$ [K:H \cap K] = p$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Can a kind algebraist offer an improvement to this sketch of a proof?
Proof.  $H \triangleleft G$, $[G:H]=p$, $K \notin H$, $K < G$.
Take $\pi: G \rightarrow G/H$
$x \longmapsto  xH$
$K/_{H  \cap  K} \simeq KH / _H$
done if KH = G
$H \lneq KH < G$
so KH = G, by the correspondence theorem,
  and $|K/_{H \cap K}| = |KH/_H| = |G/_H| = p.$
The property holds, $[K:H \cap  K] = p$.

Comment: I believe this is what you are trying to do, but you just need to show that $K/H\cap K \cong \pi(K)$ and $\pi(K) = G/H$.

Answer (score 2):

Your "so $\;KH=G\;$ by the..." seems taken a little out of the blue. The point is that

$$p=[G:H]=[G:HK][HK:H]\iff\begin{cases}[G:HK]=1&\,,\;\; \\{}\\\text{or}\\{}\\ [HK:H]=1\end{cases}$$

But the second option is impossible since then

$$[HK:H]=1\implies H=HK\implies K\le H\;,\;\;\text{contradiction}$$

Thus, it must be $\;[G:HK]=1\implies HK=G\;$